# free memory of DataSet in Spark 2.2. standalone

Tags: scala, apache-spark, memory

I'm using `Spark 2.2/2.3` from `Scala` to process a bunch of large CSV files using Spark SQL and the `Scala Dataset/Dataframe` collection API (map, filter, etc).

I'm currently observing that Spark exceeds the memory limits set by `spark.executor.memory` (8 GB) significantly on my development laptop. The memory usage of the JVM running the driver/executor climbs up to ~16 GB of Heap usage (observed with jvisualvm during execution, see picture below). The linux htop shows at peak ~16.6 GB RES and 21.8 GB VIRT memory usage. On the production system, the process seems to grab even more memory (reportedly ~33GB) with the same spark configuration.

During execution I took a look at the executor memory usage using the Spark web UI - I saw somthing like 12.2GB/8.8GB executor memory (in production, the UI is off).

I know that the actual executor memory limit depends not only on the spark.executor.memory config, but also on some additional fiddle factors which explain the additional 0.8 GB of executor memory. The driver needs also memory, as far as I could find in the doc it takes by default ~1GB of memory.

- How is it then possible that the Spark UI shows 12.2 GB **executor** memory usage?
- Why ist the VIRT memory usage of the JVM so much higher?

[image: memory footprint]

But, more importantly, what can I do during driver program execution to free unused DataSets?

Example:

- read files `fa`, `fb` into the datasets `dsA, dsB`.
- do some filtering and mapping on `dsA, dsB` => `dsA1, dsB1`.
- call `dsA1 & dsB1.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)` to avoid rereading and reprocessing.
- join `dsA1` and `dsB1` to create a `dsAB2`.
- `dsAB2.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)`
- continue using `dsAB2` only

=> assumptions: I can now "drop" `dsA, dsB, dsA1` and `dsB1` to free the memory used by them.

I called:

- `dsA1.unpersist(true); dsA1= null; dsA= null`
- `dsB1.unpersist(true); dsB1= null; dsB= null`

Now the garbage collector should free up some of the gigabytes used by the datasets. But even after nudging the GC with `System.getRuntime().gc()` I can see no significant change in the JVM heap memory usage while observing with jvisualvm.

Is there any trick to really discard unused datasets/dataframes?